# Making a request to Dynamics CRM Web API

Tags: python, azure, urllib2, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to make an app that makes requests to Dynamics CRM Web API from python using urllib2.
So far I can login an user with an Azure application by making a post request to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
then with the retrieved authorization_code I can get the access_token, refresh_token and others with urllib2

```
url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'
post_fields = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
                'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
                'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
                'code': code}  
request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
resp = urlopen(request).read().decode()
resp = json.loads(resp)
refresh_token = resp['refresh_token']
id_token = resp['id_token']
id_token = jwt.decode(id_token,verify=False)
access_token = resp['access_token']
```

Then I tried to make another post request by using the access_token but had no luck. 
I keep getting:

> HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Just as a test I make a post directly to .dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/leads
as follows:

```
url = 'https://<company_uri>.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/leads'
post_fields = {"name": "Sample Account",
                "creditonhold": "false",
                "address1_latitude": 47.639583,
                "description": "This is the description of the sample account",
                "revenue": 5000000,
                "accountcategorycode": 1
               }
request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token )
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
request.add_header('OData-MaxVersion','4.0')
request.add_header('OData-Version','4.0')
request.add_header('Accept','application/json')
resp = urlopen(request).read().decode()
```

But i keep getting the same 401 error code.
I've looked all over msdn documentation but didn't find the way to do this directly without using any library, I just want to use a simple post request.

Since the error code says Unauthorized I think the access_token must be sent in some other way.
Can someone help me on how to correctly use the access_token on Dynamics CRM?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access token you got back is for the Azure AD Graph API. Not Dynamics CRM.

To call that, you must ask for an access token with *resource* set to Dynamics CRM API's App ID URI, not `https://graph.windows.net`.

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx) you should set *resource* to `https://<company_uri>.crm.dynamics.com`.

So when you are retrieving token:

```
url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'
post_fields = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
                'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
                'resource': 'https://<company_uri>.crm.dynamics.com',
                'code': code}
```

Comment: I had changed the resource once before but I never got the answer, I was always getting "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". With the https://graph.microsoft.com resource I was getting a code but now I understand that of course it was usefull because that's not the resource I want access granted.
I did change the resource now, but I'm getting that 400 error.

Comment: You should read the response, it'll say what was the problem.

Comment: "The user or administrator has not consented to use the application". The original problem was because of the wrong resource, so I think this was solved. Thanks @juunas .

Comment: Yeah, that's a separate, common issue,  you can find an answer for that here surely.