# How do I authenticate to create a model-driven power app via the web api?

Tags: python, dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

When following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/create-manage-model-driven-apps-using-code) to create a model-driven power app using code, what steps do I need to take to successfully make this post request below, which is a replication of the first one in the linked docs. I am currently getting a status of 401.

```
import requests
url = "https://<OrganizationURI>.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/appmodules"
header = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0",
"OData-Version": "4.0",
"Accept": "application/json"
}
data = {
    "name": "SDKTestApp",
    "uniquename":"SDKTestApp",
    "webresourceid":"953b9fac-1e5e-e611-80d6-00155ded156f"    
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=data)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: A `401` is an `"Unauthorized"` response.   Apparently, you need to do something to authenticate with the endpoint that you are calling.  Are you really running this code with "<OrganizationURI>" in the URL?  I assume that that has to be replaced by something.  What is it that is hosting the endpoint that your are trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

The guide talks about basic payload for that endpoint to work. That will work as is when the code is running inside Dynamics CRM/Model driven powerapp.

For outside code execution, we need token by using client Id and secret. Before that you have to [register in the AAD app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/mt622431(v=crm.8)). You can refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41786709).